# How to work with dynamic strings in Cobol?

Tags: c, string, cobol85

There is a C- code
`char* str = NULL; str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);`

Could I write the same thing in Cobol-85?

Or maybe I can use
`01  LE                USAGE IS POINTER.`
pass it into C-lang function and allocate memory and fill string there and use this pointer on Cobol side for displaying string content? Like

```
call CFUNC using
by reference LE   
by descriptor "TEST STRING"  
giving LE.  
display LE.
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, that C code is not very nice. First of all, why initialized `str` with `NULL` to begin with? Why not initialize it by calling `malloc` directly in the definition of `str`? Also, `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be equal to `1`, so you never need to multiply with it. And lastly in C you [don't need to cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc-and-do-i-pass-the-size-of-the-type-or-the-object).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your answer, but the question was about another thing. What about casting, etc. it is necessary on the Alpha OpenVMS platform because of local compiler specific.

Comment: @AntonGolovenko Which compiler are you using?  The dynamic allocation of memory is not something universally supported or even standardized.